# Knockout Observable array not being observed?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let me start with [a screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/LdloDEVE7PK) of the current behaviour. As you can see, when I add a role for the user **jbrown**, the role doesn't show where it should!

But if I navigate away to another user, then back to **jbrown**, the role(s) does show!

Here is the ViewModel in question:

```
function UsersViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  // data with some removed for brevity
  self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);
  self.selectedUser = ko.observable();
  self.SelectedUserHasRoles = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.isLoaded()) {
      return self.selectedUser().roles().length > 0;
    }
    return false;
  });

  self.UserHasAllAvailableRoles = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.isLoaded()) {
      return self.userAvailableRoles().length === 0;
    }
    return false;
  });

  // isLoaded gets set to true when AJAX call to server
  // is a success and data is returned

  // operations with some removed for brevity
  self.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
    const newRolesArray = self.roles().filter(function (role) {
      return !contains(user.roles(), role);
    });
    self.userAvailableRoles(newRolesArray);
    self.selectedUser(user);
  }

  self.addUser = function () {
    self.users.push(new User({ Username: this.newUsernameText() }));
    self.newUsernameText('');
    self.NewUserFormIsVisible(false);
    self.AddRolesFormIsVisible(true);
    self.setCurrentUser(self.users()[self.users().length - 1]);
  };

  self.addRoleForSelectedUser = function() {
    self.selectedUser().roles().push(new Role({ Name: self.selectedRole().name() }));
    self.AddRolesFormIsVisible(false);
    $.post('http://localhost:23926/admin/acl/addusertorole', { username: self.selectedUser().name(), role: self.selectedRole().name() },
    function () {
      console.log('user role created at db!');
    },
    'json');
  }
}
```

And here is the HTML markup in question:

```
<!-- ko if: isLoaded -->
  <!-- ko if: SelectedUserHasRoles() -->
  <div class="roles-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedUser().roles()">
    <div class="role-token" data-bind="text: name()"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

My Observable array of roles must be getting populated because as you saw, when I navigate away and back, I can see the roles I've added.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the code that adds the role?

Comment: added the code for the `addRoleForSelectedUser` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to push the new role to the underlying, untracked, array instead of the observable array.

```
self.addRoleForSelectedUser = function() {
    self.selectedUser().roles().push(new Role({ Name: self.selectedRole().name() }));
    ...
}
```

You just need to remove the set of parenthesis after "roles" so that it looks like:

```
self.selectedUser().roles.push(new Role({ Name: self.selectedRole().name() }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.selectedUser().roles().push(
```

do

```
self.selectedUser().roles.push(
```

That will use the ObservableArray member function `push` rather than the underlying array's `push`. The difference is that Knockout only notices the changes made through its member functions.

Comment: Thanks, you were right too. Jason was faster by a couple of seconds lol